# What is the difference between NPTL and POSIX threads?

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix, nptl

What is the basic difference between NPTL and POSIX threads? How have these two evolved?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

POSIX threads (pthread) is not an implementation, it is a API specification (a standard, on paper, in english) of several functions whose name starts with `pthread_` and which are defined in `<pthread.h>` header. POSIX is also a set of specifications.

NPTL is now inside [GNU Libc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) on Linux and is (or at least tries very hard to be) an implementation of POSIX threads. It is a bunch of source and binary code on your Linux system.
An application compiled with `gcc -pthread` and linked with `-pthread` uses NPTL code on Linux today.

#### addenda

There exist alternative implementations of `pthread`-s: on Linux, the [MUSL Libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) aims to be Posix compliant (which means having pthreads); on other Posix systems (AIX, Solaris, ...) you also have pthreads (but they are not NPTL or Glibc).

Comment: So `-lpthread` and `-pthread` both use the NPTL implementation?

Comment: Yes, on most Linux systems (but you could install MUSL libc)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, i am trying to figure out how musl doesn't break the build of code that links with a "-lpthread".  I am trying to build our code which makes light use of pthreads, mutex, and cond against musl.  It builds and links fine, but the thread behavior is truly odd.  I looked at the configure script for musl but there does not seem to be any special switches for pthread.

Answer (score 9):

"POSIX threads" is a 'standard', defining an API for threading. i.e. it states that functions such as `pthread_exit ()` etc, should exist in the system, and describes how they should behave. All POSIX compliant operating systems implement POSIX threads in their own way.

NPTL is a bunch of features that enables "Linux" (the kernel) to efficiently implement "POSIX threads" (the standard).

You can read more about NPTL and how it came about [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library)

Comment: If i understand correctly, POSIX thread is implemented in Linux, by using NPTL library ?

Comment: I guess that is correct. I added a link to Wikipedia [Google is your friend :)]

Answer (score 4):

I guess your best source of information is starting on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPTL) and following the links from there.

There is really no difference: NPTL is just the current Linux implementation of POSIX threads, you still use the pthread_* family of functions. Earlier in Linux history, a dedicated library called libpthreads was used. NPTL appeared for 2.6+ kernels circa 2003, see the link above for more details.

[BTW: NPTL == Native Posix Threads Library]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, u mean to say NPTL and pthread both are using same API, but implementation is different ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. NPTL makes use of the more advanced facilities available for task creation introduced with Linux kernel 2.6.+.

Comment: So, Do We have two set of libraries one for NPTL and another one is for pthread ?.. IF so, can i how can i link to NPTL library to my program?.

Comment: Nonononono. NPTL has been the standard POSIX threads library for a very long time now. At the time of the switch (more than 7 years ago), yes, you'd have had to choose, but now it is standard. As the Wikipedia entry says, it is now standard in glibc, and has been for a long time.

Comment: pthread is NOT the same as NPTL. pthread is a Standard. NPTL is how Linux and GNU Libc implement it. If you make calls to pthread_* functions and include pthread.h in your program, and compile and run it on a fairly recent GNU/Linux machine, it will inherently use NPTL. POSIX threads are a feature provided by every POSIX compliant Operating System.